# Non-Transactional Commands Closes Database in OrienttDB

Tags: java, orientdb

Within an open transaction the creation of a vertex type, which is non-transactional, closes the database, that was opened before. The following example throws an exception:

```
public class OrientDBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url = "plocal:/Users/d022051/tmp/orientdbtest";
        final OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(url);
        final OrientGraph graphTx = factory.getTx();
        final ODatabaseDocumentTx documentTx = graphTx.getRawGraph();
        final OrientGraphNoTx graphNoTx = factory.getNoTx();

        graphTx.begin();

        OrientVertexType sequenceClassType = graphNoTx.createVertexType("Sequence");
        sequenceClassType.createProperty("No", OType.LONG).setMin("0").setDefaultValue("0");
        sequenceClassType.createProperty("Name", OType.STRING);

        OSQLSynchQuery<ODocument> selectSequenceCommand = new OSQLSynchQuery<>("select from Sequence where Name = 'GLOBAL'");
        List<ODocument> sequences = documentTx.query(selectSequenceCommand);
        if (sequences.isEmpty()) {
            graphTx.addVertex("class:" + "Sequence", "Name", "GLOBAL");
        }
        graphTx.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The exception says "the current database is not open on the current thread". Whereas if the graphTx.begin() statement is moved down after the creation of the vertex type, everything is fine. So the graphNoTx command is closing the database for documentTx. I assume the reason is that schema changes cannot be done when a transaction is still open, and thus the transaction is implicitly closed. But, actually the transaction is still open, and a subsequent command using graphTx is successful:

```
public class OrientDBTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String url = "plocal:/Users/d022051/tmp/orientdbtest";
        final OrientGraphFactory factory = new OrientGraphFactory(url);
        final OrientGraph graphTx = factory.getTx();
        final ODatabaseDocumentTx documentTx = graphTx.getRawGraph();
        final OrientGraphNoTx graphNoTx = factory.getNoTx();

        graphTx.begin();

        OrientVertexType sequenceClassType = graphNoTx.createVertexType("Sequence");
        sequenceClassType.createProperty("No", OType.LONG).setMin("0").setDefaultValue("0");
        sequenceClassType.createProperty("Name", OType.STRING);

        graphTx.addVertex("class:" + "Sequence", "Name", "GLOBAL");

        graphTx.shutdown();
    }
}
```

This runs without error. This looks strange? What is the reason?

Comment: Read this
http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Multi-Threading.html

Comment: I know that the database instance is per thread. But in my example everything happens on the same thread.

Comment: But you have two database instances one tx and one noTx

Comment: But then there should be an error also in my second example when graphTx is called after graphNoTx. But that works fine. Only in the case with the documentTx. The documentation of getRawGraph says that it returns the underlying database. Thus I would not expext a different behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

@wolf4ood is right. In your code you create transactional graph instance with new  database attached to it and  make this database active `final OrientGraph graphTx = factory.getTx();` then you make active 
non-tx graph instance with new database instance (not the same as first one) by calling of  `final OrientGraphNoTx graphNoTx = factory.getNoTx();` but then with active non-tx graph database you try to start transaction on not active database which belongs to tx-instance of graph.

How to avoid this. It is very simple just execute following code before acquiring any graph instance `factory.setupPool(5, 15)`. This code will create database pool. Pool has following feature - for the same database URL and the same thread the same database instance will be returned (does not matter whether you acquire transactional graph or not).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I unterstand the explanation and will use the Pool. Still, sorry for asking again: Why do the two examples behave differently? DocumentTx and graphTx should be assigned to the same DB, and thus I would expext that both cases fail after graphNoTx became active. What is happening there?

Comment: With the pool there is another exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraphNoTx cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientTransactionalGraph. This exception is thrown, when the VertexType is going to be created. The unfortunate conclusion seems to be that I cannot use the pool.

Comment: @Gregor Could you create issue about this exception ?